# See how website generates a random number?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So on a site like [this](https://csgoroll.com/en/roulette), a random number is generated that will dictate the outcome of the roll. But since you can check out the source code, set breakpoints, etc. from the developer console, is it also possible to find the implementation used to generate these random numbers? I have tried (looked through sources and set breakpoints), however, I cannot find it. How would you approach such task and is it even possible to find for a website like this?

Answer (score 2):

Random number generation for sites like that is done on the backend. The backend source code is not visible just by visiting the website.

Comment: Is everything within the "sources" tab frontend? :/

Comment: Everything you can see is frontend, so yes. It's not possible to get implementation of the random number generator on the backend.